# Under what circumstances would a Ruby $LOAD_PATH be acquired from a parent process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cucumber, bundler

In my cucumber scenarios, if I call `rake db:schema:load` within a target Rails app folder, I get the cucumber process's $LOAD_PATH and not the Rails app's own Gemfile/load path. I think this is very weird.

The consequence is that I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- rails/all
```

I can't reproduce it outside of my cucumber scenario.

```
ruby -rubygems -e "system 'rake -T'"
```

works normally -> the 'rake -T' has the application's own Gemfile-based $LOAD_PATH; and doesn't generate the error above.

Can anyone think why a child process (`rake -T` or `rake db:schema:load` or `rails runner...`; invoked by either `system`, `exec`, `%x[...]` or backtick; would start with the parent processes' $LOAD_PATH (from the cucumber scenario's Gemfile) instead of its own $LOAD_PATH (from the Rails app's Gemfile)?

Answer (score 2):

When you use bundler, either via `bundle exec` or `require 'bundler/setup'`, it finds your Gemfile, then puts its location in `ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"]`. However, if this is already set, then bundler just reuses the value. This is what causes your Rails app to use the cucumber process's Gemfile.

If you want to execute something in the context of a different Gemfile, clear out `ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"]` first. Bundler provides the method `Bundler.with_clean_env(&blk)` that may be helpful; it executes your block with the environment how it was before Bundler was loaded. Of course, you can also clear it out by hand with something like `system("env -u BUNDLE_GEMFILE rake sometask")`.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely true if you're doing "Bundler Inception" (multiple levels of Bundler invocation).  Note also that Rails apps set `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']` in `config/boot.rb`, which even `Bundler.with_clean_env` will not catch.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process's environment (`ENV`) is passed down to sub-shells. Either cucumber itself, how you are running cucumber (e.g. `bundle exec cucumber`), your scenarios, or code the scenario loads (e.g. the app, and therefore bundler), is messing with your `ENV`. Environment variables like `RUBYLIB`, `GEM_PATH`, and `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` can have a significant impact on what your sub-shelled Ruby processes can load / will behave.

Try printing out your `ENV` variable in your scenario and comparing it to what you get when you do it with `ruby -rubygems -rpp -e "pp ENV"`, or just `env` on the command line.

For what it's worth, a possible alternative would be to load and invoke the rake task directly, e.g., `Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke`, without using a sub-shell. Depends on what you're trying to do, though.